# EF Core: A many to many relationship on the same table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have this class:

```
    public class Produto
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; } = String.Empty;
//other stuff
        public ICollection<Produto>? ProdutosRelacionados { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a table "Produto" that has many "Produto" (related products, as in every e-commerce)
How do I implement it in the fluent API?
Thanks

I tried to manualy configure a link table. EF core does not let me do the migration. You cannot create a class with two forigner keys for the same table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You MUST configure a two way navigation, so you have to create another property

...

```
public ICollection<Produto>? ProdutoPai{ get; set; }
```

...

And then configure it on the fluent API like so

...

```
builder.Entity<Produto>(ent => {
//outras configs da entidade...
ent.HasMany(p => p.ProdutosRelacionados)
.WithMany(p => p.ProdutoPai)
.UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("ProdutosRelacionados"));
});
```

...

Comment: Thanks for posting how you answered your own question. The community sometimes takes more than a day or two to answer questions that they haven't encountered themselves. We hope you ask and answer more questions!